# Is it possible to create a javascript api that only allows certain domains to call it

Tags: javascript, api, http, rest

I want to provide my data to different websites through a Javascript API, and I don't want the others to have to modify their backend code.

I believe the best way to do this is by providing JSONP to the other websites (please correct me if I am wrong).

However I don't want just anyone to be able to use the API - what are my options for controlling usage of the API.

Answer (score 2):

If the API is called by the JS running on the remote website you could use CORS (check IE support).

But if you need more granular control on your API usage you must use a key and check the referer against the key.

Btw even using a key someone can make a script faking the referer and thus using your API.

But if it's a JS API there's no alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have many experiences with JavaScript APIs, but I know that there isn't a real way to secure your JavaScript code.
If your Code is used in any Website there is always a way to get to it.